# The axes when I move/rotate/scale is different from those of the world

Tags: axis

[image]

I must've touched something wrong so my axes are acting weird. It seems like the axes are heading towards where the object is facing. How do I make them the same with the world axes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can choose whatever transform orientation you want to use instead of Local. if you are constraining transforms to some axis with shortcuts <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd> or middle mouse button, you can just hit it again with Local orientation set to temporarily use global orientation anyway:

[image]

This works the other way around if you have global orientation selected as well.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew you can do that. Previously in 2.79b, I used to press G + X if I want to move objects in x axle, R + Y if to rotate in y axle, S + Z to scale in z axle. I suppose shortcuts are the unchanged in 2.8x,